# C++ Issue with File I/O within Parent and Child Classes

Tags: c++, io, polymorphism, parent-child

I have a programming assignment and I am stuck on this last part.  I need to read input in from a .txt file.  The parent class is a railroad car and the children are tank cars and box cars, each with a readData class function.

Here is the sample input from the .txt:

```
T
T001
3/14/14
F
1550
```

The first line distinguishes between a boxcar and a tank car and my main() handles this fine.  The next two lines read in are the serial number and the date it was serviced.  The final two lines are handled by the tank car child class readData function.  I need help reading in the serial number and the date.

```
bool RRCar::ReadData(istream& input)
{
    string date, serial;

    if (input.good())
    {
        getline(input, serial, '\n');
        RRCar::SetSerial(serial);
        getline(input, date, '\n');
        RRCar::SetServiceDate(date);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Why is it not reading in the data properly?  Additionally, here are the setters:

```
void RRCar::SetSerial(const string& NewSerial)
{
    serialNum = NewSerial;
}

void RRCar::SetServiceDate(const string& NewDate)
{
    serviceDate = NewDate;
}
```

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Okay a few things, is the format of your text file: T T001 3...blah or T\nT001, ie is the separator a space or newline. What do you mean its not reading the data properly? In your code, serial will get T and date will get T001 assuming your separator in the text file is a '\n'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure your only issue is that you aren't skipping over the first line. If your text file is separated using new lines and you are using getline, you don't need to specify the delimiter (as default is newline ([see reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)) but you do need to iterate over the first line (that you don't need in this function).

Then we have:

```
bool RRCar::ReadData(istream& input)
{
    string date, serial;

    if (input.good())
    {
        getline(input, serial); //Dummy call
        getline(input, serial);

        //Check to see if stream is still good, ie no eofbit, failbit, badbit flags set for input
        if( input.good() ) 
            RRCar::SetSerial(serial);

        getline(input, date)

        if( input.good() ) 
            RRCar::SetServiceDate(date);

        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

`serialNum` and `serviceDate` should now contain the correct values.

With my input of:

```
T
T001
3/14/14
F
1550
```

I got a final state:
`serialNum = T001` and `serviceDate = 3/14/14`

Comment: Using the values read by `std::getline` without checking to see whether the call succeeded is a good way to end up with undefined behavior down the line.

Comment: You are correct but I provided the simplest solution. Ideally you went check if the result of read was good. Some programming assignments state that you can assume data input is valid though!

Comment: Using `input.good()` to check for success is not correct; it can return `false` even if the read succeeded.

Comment: @JamesKanze The 3 flags checked (set by getline call) is the eofbit, badbit and failbit. If they aren't set then the read was in fact 'good'. It only returns false if one of those flags are set, otherwise it returns true and the read was completed successfully.

Comment: @Mohammad `eofbit` may be set even if the input succeeded.  There is no correct use of `good()`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should open a file to read first, before using getline().

Comment: I think the OPs function receives an already opened `std::istream`, from an already opened file, standard input or whatever.

Comment: The input parameter is an istream, he has opened the file elsewhere.